Network tab Payload doesn't match model properties
I'm working with ASP.NET Core 8 MVC and trying to add reCAPTCHA v2 to a partial page included in a larger page.
The partial looks like this:
@model NewsletterSubscription

<h4>Join Our Newsletter</h4>
<hr />
<p>Share your email email with us to stay connected.</p>
<form asp-controller="Newsletter" asp-action="Create" method="post" id="newsletterForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="subscriptionAddress" name="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <!-- reCAPTCHA v2 widget -->
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey={correct site key} data-callback="recaptchaCallback">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="RecaptchaResponse" id="RecaptchaResponse" /> 
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    function recaptchaCallback(token) {
        console.log("reCAPTCHA token generated:", token);
        document.getElementById('RecaptchaResponse').value = token;
        console.log("recaptchaCallback: RecaptchaResponse set to: ", document.getElementById('RecaptchaResponse').value);
    }

    document.getElementById("newsletterForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        // Explicitly set the RecaptchaResponse field value before form submission
        let token = document.getElementById('RecaptchaResponse').value;
        console.log("Submit event: RecaptchaResponse value before submit:", token)
        document.getElementById('RecaptchaResponse').value = token;
        console.log("Form submitted. RecaptchaResponse value:", document.getElementById('RecaptchaResponse').value);
    });
</script>

@section Scripts {
    <!-- Load reCAPTCHA v2 script -->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}

The model looks like this:
public class NewsletterSubscription
{
    private Guid id;
    private string emailAddress;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the email address
    /// </summary>
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return emailAddress; }
        set
        {
            id = new Guid();
            emailAddress = value;
            updatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        }
    }

    // ...

    /// <summary>
    /// RecaptchaResponse is used to tell if Recaptcha has validated that the submitter is not a bot
    /// </summary>
    private string recaptchaResponse;
    [NotMapped]
    public string RecaptchaResponse
    {
        get { return recaptchaResponse; }
        set { recaptchaResponse = value; }
    }
}

When debugging, I can see that the RecaptchaResponse property is getting set, but the value is null. From the browser console debugging, I can see that the reCAPTCHA is passing and the token is being received and the value of the RecaptchaResponse field is being set to the token.
image of console debugging
However, when I look at the Payload in the Dev Tools Network tab, a field called 'g-recaptcha-response' is being populated with the token value:
image 1 of Dev Tools Network tab Payload
and the 'RecaptchaResponse' field is null:
image 2 of Dev Tools Network tab Payload
I don't have a field called g-recaptcha-response - where is this field coming from? And why is RecaptchaResponse null?
